# Как получить user_id при вводе команды /start (aiogram 2.24)

Tags: python, бот, aiogram-2.x

`@dp.message_handler(commands= 'start') async def command_start(message: types.Message): await message.answer("текст")`

Есть такой код, нужно чтобы при отправке команды /start в переменную записывался user_id получений при вводе

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
@dp.message_handler(commands= 'start') 
async def command_start(message: types.Message): 
   await message.answer("текст")
   user_id=message.from_user.id
   username=message.from_user.username
```

Comment: Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1486726/edit)».